# .Net core, publish to Plesk. 500 - Internal server error

Tags: .net, compiler-errors, .net-core, publish, plesk

As the title says, I'm trying to publish my website to Plesk but when I visit it i get this error:
[image]

It has successfully created the tables in the database and so on.
So the connection towards the MS SQl database seems to work.
I've also tried adding this to a web.config file, but it didn't change the error message...:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And also I've tried adding this to the startup without any success with the error message:

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong?

Really grateful for every answer.